# How can I change the font type of 'Logout'

Tags: html

Hi does anyone know how to make the Logout! text white?

```
  echo "Welcome, ".$_SESSION['username']."!<br><a href='logout.php'>Logout!";

    <font color="#ffffff">your text</font>
```

Comment: Add style="color: white" to your <a> tag

Comment: This has nothing todo with php. This is `css` related. [See](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_text.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
echo "Welcome, ".$_SESSION['username']."!<br><a href='logout.php' style='color: #ffffff;'>Logout!</a>";
```